# Shrink size of videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have something like 40gb of video plots of math functions in mp4 format, I would like to shrink them, by optimizing and maybe also reducing the size of thepictures of the plot to 60%. In the end I would like to have (if possible) between 5 and 10gb of size. Is it there any way to compress the videos minimizing the quality loss?
I would finally prefer a command-line solution since the amount of videos is exceeding 2000.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4
```

use or update the codex to libx265.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it reduces the size by only ~10%.